# NgIf inside click Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

HI I have the following button(s):

```
<button *ngFor="let btn of _formBtn" [type]="(btn.type=='submit')?'submit':'button'" 
            class="btn btn-icon" 
            [ngClass]="btn.class" 
            (click) = "_btnClick(btn, _finalConfig, _formBtn)" 
            [disabled]="btn.disabled"
            [hidden]="btn.hidden">
            <i *ngIf="btn.BtnType!='next'" [class]="btn.icon"></i>
            <span>{{btn.label}}</span>
            <i *ngIf="btn.BtnType=='next'" [class]="btn.icon"></i>
        </button>
```

It works fine. But now I want to modify the logic so that whenever the `btn.label` becomes 'confirmed', I want to call another function instead of `_btnClick` function. How can I modify my existing click event based on the condition? like ex: `(click) = *ngIf="btn.label=='confirmed'"? _confirmBtnClicked(btn, _finalConfig, _formBtn) : "_btnClick(btn, _finalConfig, _formBtn);"` Am quiet confused guys. Any idea how to do that guys? Or any other better suggestions for my scenario? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Can you not try having 1 handler and add if inside it to call necessary function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call another method where you can check for the same like:

```
(click) = "_confirmedClick()"
```

then in your component:

```
public _confirmedClick(){
    if(this.btn.label === "confirmed"){
        this._confirmBtnClicked(this.btn, this._finalConfig, this._formBtn);
    }else{
        this._btnClick(this.btn, this._finalConfig, this._formBtn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jai! Didn't think that way!

Answer (score 0):

Create one method like `clickMe()` and pass the `btn.label` in it.
Then according to the label you can again call different methods based on the value of the `btn.label`

Vinod